# How to call commas separated values within preg_match

Tags: php, replace, preg-match, explode, implode

```
$values = 'apple,orange,banana,mango';
```

```
public static function likecheck( $data) {
    if(preg_match("/( apple | orange | banana | mango )/i", $data) === 1) {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

I want my **$values** to be called dynamically within **preg_match** as   **apple | orange | banana | mango**

Comment: The spaces around the values are suspicious, are you sure you need them? If you need whole word match, just use `\b`. If your `values` can contain special regex metachars, they must be escaped, and then `\b` might not be a good fit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I needed the SPACE as well.

Comment: Then you need `$regexValues = ' ' . implode(' | ', explode(',', $values)) . ' ';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just explode by comma and 'glue' all together with implode

```
$values = 'apple,orange,banana,mango';
$regexValues = implode(' | ', explode(',', $values));

if(preg_match("/ $regexValues /i", $data) === 1) {
    return true; 
}
```